# simple form action how to "exclude #"

Tags: html, forms

First of all, here`s my code:

```
<form action="http://shpapp01/Web/Public.html#/PublicWeb/Tracking/Search">
Bill: <input type="text" name="Reference" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

It should work like this:

When I click on Search, the URL should change to `"shpapp01/Web/Public.html#/PublicWeb/Tracking/Search?Reference=submitted_text"`

But it always gives me this:

`"shpapp01/Web/Public.html#?Reference=submitted_text/PublicWeb/Tracking/Search"`

because of the # in the link.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in jaavscript:

```
var f = document.querySelector("form");
text = f.action;
text2 = text.replace("Public.html#", "Public.html");
f.action = text2;
```

Comment: I made some edits if you have a problem just recheck the answer